# Set Stripe Billing Address Default Country Android SDK

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I'm implementing Stripe on an Android app.  There is a requirement to present the billing address fields when the user adds a card, we do that by implementing the following:

```
PaymentSessionConfig.Builder()
                    .setShippingInfoRequired(false)
                    .setShippingMethodsRequired(false)
                    .setBillingAddressFields(BillingAddressFields.Full)
                    .setPaymentMethodTypes(listOf(PaymentMethod.Type.Card))
                    .setShouldShowGooglePay(false)
                    .build()
```

By default when the user adds a card `United States` is the default country selected on the billing address.  I need to change the default country to another.  I've been researching but I haven't seen the option.

Is there a way to update the config to set the default country of the billing address, or some other method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The default country selected in the dropdown looks to be set by the user's locale: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/9f1f39ba8bba149c5c825769262a240a7f8dd26e/stripe/src/test/java/com/stripe/android/paymentsheet/ui/BillingAddressViewTest.kt#L30-L35. As far as I can tell this is not configurable.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  If that is indeed the case, something isn't working right as I am in Europe and default is US.. I might make further enquiries.. Thanks again

Comment: Currently, I'm looking into this. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the Billing address country programatically on the PaymentSheet by:

1. Creating an Address

   ```
   PaymentSheet.Address address = new 
   PaymentSheet.Address("FillWithCityName",
   ```

"FillWithCountryIntials", null, null, null, "FillWithCountryName");

2. Creating a BillingDetails object and assigning the address created above

   ```
   PaymentSheet.BillingDetails.Builder billingDetails = new 
   PaymentSheet.BillingDetails.Builder().address(address);
   ```
3. Creating a PaymentSheet.Configuration and assigning the Billing Details created above inside the constructor

   ```
   PaymentSheet.Configuration configuration = new        
   PaymentSheet.Configuration("FillWithBusinessName",
   FillWithCustomerObject, // replace this with yours
   FillWithGooglePayConfiguration, //replace this with yours
   FillWithColorOfButtonYouWant,
   billingDetails.build()); // this is the important line
   ```
4. Finally, assign it to the paymentSheet:

   ```
     mPaymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(mPaymentIntentClientSecret, configuration);
   ```